# Run Selenium tests on Android 4.0 in Chrome beta browser rather than the default one

Tags: android, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I'm just wondering, is there any way to run Selenium tests on Android in Chrome beta browser?
After installation of Chrome beta browser on Android 4.0 emulator, it opens default browser but not the Chrome beta when running automated tests.
Is there any way to define which Android browser should be used when running automates tests with the AndroidDriver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather, as of now its not possible to run Selenium tests on Android in Chrome beta browser as:

> Android WebDriver runs the tests against a WebView (rendering
>   component used by the Android browser) configured like the Android
>   browser.

You can avail more information [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver#Introduction) and look out for future updates.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like there is no way to run tests on Android Chrome for now unless it becomes browser by default for Android devices I think.

Comment: It isn't so much Chrome being the "default" but Chrome becoming the engine behind the WebView. This happened in Android 4.4 (KitKat). I assume the APK for the WebDriver will need to be rebuilt with SDK level 19+ for the WebView to be close to the real Chrome browser. Otherwise on 4.4 devices the driver's webview will act more like the old browser (see https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html).